# AWS Lambda S3 trigger on multiple uploads

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm looking to implement an AWS Lambda function that is triggered by the input of an audio file to my s3 bucket, and then concatenates this file with the previously uploaded file (already stored in the bucket), and outputs this concatenated file back to the bucket. I'm quite new to Lambda and I'm wondering, is possible to pass in a list of file names to process into a Lambda function to transcode? Or does Lambda only accept one read at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Lambda gets invoked by S3 directly, it will get an event that looks similar to this one from [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html):

```json
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.1",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-2",
      "eventTime": "2019-09-03T19:37:27.192Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "AWS:AIDAINPONIXQXHT3IKHL2"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "205.255.255.255"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "D82B88E5F771F645",
        "x-amz-id-2": "vlR7PnpV2Ce81l0PRw6jlUpck7Jo5ZsQ"
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "828aa6fc-f7b5-4305-8584-487c791949c1",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "lambda-artifacts-deafc19498e3f2df",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "A3I5XTEXAMAI3E"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::lambda-artifacts-deafc19498e3f2df"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "b21b84d653bb07b05b1e6b33684dc11b",
          "size": 1305107,
          "eTag": "b21b84d653bb07b05b1e6b33684dc11b",
          "sequencer": "0C0F6F405D6ED209E1"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It gives you basic meta information about the object that was uploaded.
There's no way to customize this event, but a Lambda function can query external resources for more information.

---

You could also use S3-Batching, but that's probably not designed for your use case.